# Как указать cmake где генерировать проект?

Tags: cmake

Нужно сгенерировать проект в другой папке а не текущей. Как это сделать?

Comment: запускать cmake из папки, в которой генерировать проект, не?

Comment: Не, там bash скрипт

Comment: непонятно. где-что... подробный [mcve] в студию...

Comment: Что не понятно? Нужно сделать так что бы cmake генерировал файлы проекта не в той папке в которой запущен а в той которая передана через параметр командной строки. Вот что за параметр я так и не нашёл. Можно передать через переменные пути для файлов сборки компилятором. А вот как путь до генерации проекта я так и не нашёл как.

Comment: @Andu, просто зачем его передавать, если можно запустить cmake в нужном каталоге?

Comment: Выше написал что вставлю в bash  скрипт. Если использовать вашь вариант то надо сохранить текущий путь. Перейти в нужный. Выполнить cmake . И вернуться назад. Хочу просто одной командой.

Comment: @Andu, используй subshell и будет тебе счастье: `(cd /where/to/build && cmake /path/to/source)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ответ базируется на ответах к аналогичному вопросу: [CMake output/build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18826789/4827341)

«нормальное» (и ожидаемое пользователями) поведение программы *cmake* — создавать генерируемые файлы в текущем каталоге.

---

для описанного (редкого) случая, когда текущий каталог, каталог с исходными текстами, и каталог для генерируемых файлов («целевой») — это три разных каталога, можно пойти двумя путями.

1. запускать программу *cmake* сразу в целевом каталоге. чтобы после выполнения программы оболочка «вернулась» в текущий каталог, можно запускать программу в под-оболочке (используя круглые скобки):

   ```
   ( cd целевой/каталог && cmake каталог/с/исходниками )
   ```
2. указать программе пути к целевому каталогу и каталогу с исходниками с помощью опций `-Bпуть` и `-Hпуть` соответственно (пробелов не должно быть):

   ```
   cmake -Bцелевой/каталог -Hкаталог/с/исходниками
   ```